# how to get this finagle example to work?

Tags: scala, finagle

I have been looking at some finagle tutorials. I found this code for a simple server, but I can not get it to work. Should Service be specified with type so that it is possible to find the type of serve?

**Code:**

```
import com.twitter.finagle.{Http, Service}
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse, DefaultHttpResponse}
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion._
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus._
import com.twitter.util.{Future, Await}
object Server{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val service = new Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] {
    def apply(req: HttpRequest) =
        Future.value(new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK))
    }
    val server = Http.serve(":8080", service)
    Await.ready(server)
 }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error message:
Error:(25, 23) overloaded method value serve with alternatives:
  (addr: java.net.SocketAddress,service: com.twitter.finagle.ServiceFactory[com.twitter.finagle.http.Request,com.twitter.finagle.http.Response])com.twitter.finagle.ListeningServer <and>
  (addr: String,service: com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.twitter.finagle.http.Request,com.twitter.finagle.http.Response])com.twitter.finagle.ListeningServer <and>
  (addr: String,service: com.twitter.finagle.ServiceFactory[com.twitter.finagle.http.Request,com.twitter.finagle.http.Response])com.twitter.finagle.ListeningServer <and>
  (addr: java.net.SocketAddress,service: com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.twitter.finagle.http.Request,com.twitter.finagle.http.Response])com.twitter.finagle.ListeningServer
 cannot be applied to (String, com.twitter.finagle.Service[org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest,org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse]{def apply(req: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest): com.twitter.util.Future[org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpResponse]})
    val server = Http.serve(":8080", service)
                      ^
```

link: https://twitter.github.io/finagle/docs/#com.twitter.finagle.package

link to scala school code as mentioned in my comment: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/finagle.html#server

Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "finagle"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++=  Seq(
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-http" % "6.31.0",
)
```

Comment: I am having problems with several of the codes available on finagle, for instance  the server code on scala school, which gives me an error based on overloaded method value build with alternatives.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `netty` packages? Could you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @TNW. no, just copying what they are showing. By the way, I am using sbt to include libraryDependencies.

Comment: is this exactly the code of the example (I can't find it on the page)? Because your `service` is a different (netty rather than finagle) type from the what the `Http.serve` call is expecting. I suspect the import statements are causing things like Service to resolve to something different

Comment: @Paul. The code that I show here in the thread should be copied and pasted from the top link. Clicking the link I come to a view immediately seeing the code snipped ("Thus a simple HTTP server is built like this:..). The only thing I have done differently is to wrap it into a singleton (object with a main).

Comment: You should not define a Main method. Instead call it something else and let your server object extend `App`

Comment: @kao. I have successfully used main on objects before instead of extending from App. However, I tried your suggestion (called object S (extends App (removing the main)) and it doesn't resolve my issues.

Comment: Which finagle version are you using?

Comment: @kao. I decided to add my whole build.sbt content just incase there is something missing.

Comment: This finc-core looks weird to me. Did you mean finch-core? And if so, Finch is an abstraction layer on top of finagle, not actual Finagle core.

Comment: @kao. That was just redundant code (now removed) since I also tried some finch stuff. having those references in the build.sbt has no impact on the code in this thread

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102485/discussion-between-kao-and-stian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in finagle 6.30.x the Httpx package was renamed back to Http and the original Http (which contained netty http types) was removed. you should build the service with c.t.f.h.Request c.t.f.h.Response types

Comment: Thanks - i will try that.

Comment: i have updated answer in finaglers mailing list. you will need little more work to make it work.